# How to store output of logrus to some variable?

Tags: go, logging, error-logging, logrus

This is code that converts the entered value to JSON format. It shows the correct output but I want to store that output and return it using `fmt.Printf`

```golang
package main

import (
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func main() {
    log.SetFormatter(&log.JSONFormatter{})
    standardFields := log.Fields{
        "Number of threads": "1",
        "Odd number":        "3",
    }
    log.WithFields(standardFields).Info("Golang")
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: `logrus` (as other 99.9% logging packages) supports the concept of a "logger" which is a configured object which performs, well, logging in a specific way; a logger has an "output" which is an `io.Writer` responsible for storing the serialized bytes intended to be stored—see [this](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus/blob/master/logger.go#L17). So create a logger instance with a suitable output (a `bytes.Buffer` would fit, for instance) and call it a day.

Comment: This looks like a pretty clear XY Problem. What is your goal? If the goal is testing logging, for example, use the [test logger](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/sirupsen/logrus/hooks/test).  If it's for formatting your log the way you want, use a [custom formatter](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/sirupsen/logrus#readme-formatters). If your goal is to insert these "values" in a data base or something, you should write your own logger backend.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new logger with [logrus.New()](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/sirupsen/logrus#New), you can provide the `Out` field to point to any `io.Writer` you wish. Here's the documentation for this field:

```
type Logger struct {
    // The logs are `io.Copy`'d to this in a mutex. It's common to set this to a
    // file, or leave it default which is `os.Stderr`. You can also set this to
    // something more adventurous, such as logging to Kafka.
    Out io.Writer
    ...
    ...
```

So, for example you could create a new [bytes.Buffer](https://pkg.go.dev/bytes#Buffer) and set that as the `Out` field. This is akin to "logging to a variable".

Similarly, you can set the output of the *default logger* with the [SetOutput](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/sirupsen/logrus#SetOutput) function.